# PHP Codeigniter - Passed urlencode in function removes .html in url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, urlencode, urldecode

The value is correct in the URl: /optimization/page/%2Flove-your-body-club.html

But when I collect the url in the given variable in the function, the .html is removed.

```
function($url){
$urlDecoded = urldecode($url);
```

I have tried to echo out both encoded and decoded values, but the .html is still missing.

Since I use page suffix .html as default in codeigniter, it seems it reads this as not part of the passed variable.

Any workaround to this?

Comment: If I pass the string `'/optimization/page/%2Flove-your-body-club.html'` to `urldecode()` the return is `'/optimization/page//love-your-body-club.html'`. So my guess is that the value of `$url` is not what you think it is.

Comment: My question to you is, why are you forcing CodeIgniter (a PHP framework) to serve up html files? It is designed to up .php files for views and to use URIs that point to controller/method/arguments.

Comment: the thing is that it is not to show actual html files. It uses to collect data from DB for these urls. I have a db (that is, multiple actually) that collect data on URLs and the function here is a page itself that serves this data on a dashboard.

Comment: So the function itself is designed to collect data from a lot of different tables and databases, and thus need to operate on Url basis as these databases and tables have no other relation apart from the actual URL

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `url_suffix` configuration set to `.html` in `application/config/config.php`, you could just modify your function to always append the `url_suffix` to the input string.

Try this:

```
function($url) {
    $urlDecoded = urldecode($url . $this->config->item('url_suffix'));
}
```

I'd probably create a helper function that you can call everywhere in your app, maybe call it `myurldecode($url)`.

So in `application/helpers/my_helper.php` add

```
<?php

function myurldecode($url) {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return urldecode($url . $CI->config->item('url_suffix'))
}
```

And in `application/config/autoload.php` add our new helper file so that it's available everywhere:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('my_helper');
```